# A little mistake in L'Hospital's Rule using $\pi $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Just wanted to see if someone could help to fix this

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin\pi x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\pi\cos \pi x}{1}=\pi$

I just know L'Hospital's Rule it's not properly used and I think it's because

$\cos(\pi)=-1 $ and $x=0$

$\Rightarrow$ $\pi\cos \pi x = 0$

So

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin\pi x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\pi\cos \pi x}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$

Is that right or I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: L'Hospital is not applicable here since this problem does not involve a ration of the form $0/0$. In fact. here the limit does not exists: $\lim_{x\rightarrow0-}\frac{\sin(\pi x) -1}{x}=\infty$ while $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}\frac{\sin(\pi x)-1}{x}=-\infty$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin\pi x}{x}=\pi$ while $\frac{-1}{x}$ goes to infinity as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(\pi x)-1=-1\ne0$, you cannot apply L'Hopital's Rule here.

Actually, we have$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin(\pi x)-1}x=-\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sin(\pi x)-1}x=\infty;$$therefore, that limit does not exist.

Besides, note that $x=0\implies\pi\cos(\pi x)=\pi$, since $\cos(0)=1$.

Comment: This is more like a comment than a solution.

Comment: @JeanL. The question was “Is that right or I'm doing it wrong?” and I told the OP that it was wrong. *How* then is this not an answer?

Comment: Hi @JeanL. Since the question is about a mistake in using L'Hôpital's rule, and José's answer explains why you can't use L'Hôpital's rule, I consider this to be a complete answer.

Comment: @Joe:  after his edit then it looks like a solution. Before was just a mere comment with no substance.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: now that you made edits I am willing to draw my downvote. I have aberration to fast guns that want points for writing simple comments as answers. You can understand that.